# Issues with Salesforce to Salesforce sharing intermittently failing

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

We are sharing data between two Salesforce orgs (**Org1** & **Org2**) using S2S on a custom object called *Shared__c* with fields *Name* and *Shared_Field__c*. Both orgs are set up to publish the *Shared__c* object and the fields *Name* and *Shared_Field__c* to the other org. Additionally both orgs are subscribed and auto-accept the *Shared__c* object from the other org and map the *Name* and *Shared_Field__c* fields to the *Name* and *Shared_Field__c* fields in their org.

When a new *Shared__c* record is created in **Org1** with *Name="Test"* and *Shared_Field__c="New"* a record is also created in **Org2** with *Name="Test"* and *Shared_Field__c="New"* as expected. Additionally when we update *Shared_Field__c="In Progress"* in **Org2** we see that *Shared_Field__c="In Progress"* on the related record in **Org1**. All of this is as expected.

However occasionally when we update *Shared_Field__c* to a new value in **Org2** the update isn't reflected in **Org1**. When this occurs I can update *Name="Test2"* save the record, set it back to *Name="Test"* in **Org2** and then look back at **Org1** and see the update to *Shared_Field__c* is now reflected in **Org1**.

Note there are data validation rules in **Org1** on the *Valid__c* field of the *Shared__c* record. However the *Valid__c* field is not being changed after the record is created so that seems like it would be a non-issue.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this intermittent failure to push updates from **Org2** to **Org1**. Ensuring the data in **Org1** and **Org2** is critical. Aside from setting up a field called *Bogus__c* on *Shared_Field__c* and setting up a Scheduled Apex job to update *Bogus__c* on a nightly basis I am at a loss for a way to ensure the data is in sync.

We opened a case with Salesforce Support over a year ago and they not only haven't been able to identify the cause but they have also often been unresponsive.

I am wondering if anyone else in the community has experienced S2S intermittently not sharing data. If so were you able to identify the cause of the failures?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: no triggers involved on either source or target org?  `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object for record in question looks good? No data-specific validation rules on Org1?

Comment: @crop1645 What makes a `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object for the record in question look good or bad? Note that even though an update to _Shared__c_ record fails a subsequent update to the record succeeds without any change being made to the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object.

Comment: @crop1645 I believe the data validation rules in **Org1** are a non-issue as they are on a field whose value doesn't change after the _Shared__c_ record is created. There are update triggers on the _Shared__c_ object in both **Org1** and **Org2**. Does having a trigger on the object cause issues with S2S or only if the trigger fails?

Comment: PartnerNetwork RecordConnection for a given object would indicate via the Status field if the connection was suspended or still active. Given that you can resend the value again, this is at best, an unlikely possibility.  If the trigger failed, there would be an issue. Possible related items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444381/salesforce-to-salesforce-round-trip-field-update-issue; https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000188060&language=en_US

Comment: @crop1645 So a "good" `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` would be one that is still active. Then that is definitely not the case unless some weird bug in SF is setting it to inactive and then setting it back to active.

If a trigger failed I would expect to get a `Apex script unhandled trigger exception` email and I am not seeing those either so I suspect that isn't the case either. That said I will take a closer look at that code to be sure there isn't a way the trigger could fail. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've had my own adventures with S2S but not yours yet - see http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Salesforce to Salesforce syncing can fail if two updates to the same record occurs within a short time frame. It seems that this issue is caused by a problem in the way their core messaging queue works.

As I understand it, if an update message has already been queued for a particular record when another update occurs to the same record, another message is not added to the queued. When an update message is picked up from the queue the current state of the record is queried and that data is synced via S2S. This would all work just fine if the message was removed from the queue before the data was queried.

Unfortunately the message isn't removed from the queue until the sync via S2S is completed leaving a small window where updates will get lost. This seems like it would be a rare event and Salesforce even states that in their [known issue report](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XwxAAE). That said I have seen it occur many times a week.

For more details on the known issue please take a look at: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XwxAAE

Also if you believe you have been affected by this issue please click the "This Issue Affects me" button on the [known issue report](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XwxAAE). Thanks!

Comment: impressive diagnosis