# salesforce to salesforce latency

Tags: integration, salesforce-to-salesforce

I am currently evaluating salesforce-to-salesforce. I came across documentation that there is no SLA and there might be sharing delays.

I would like to know if anyone has experienced any latency issues in record sharing in Production environment?
Any insight on number of records being shared and any latency issues would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you my insight where I was trying to automatically share via an after insert/update Opportunity trigger where the Opportunity+Account were both 'unshared to the destination SFDC org'

- Trying to automatically share via insertion into `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` the Account followed by the Opportunity will not work in the same transaction.  In order to share the Opportunity, the parent Account must already be accepted by the destination system and that just doesn't happen fast enough within a single transaction.
- To work around this, I used Dan Appleman's Async Apex pattern and "scheduled" the Opportunity S2S share for +1 minute (or +5 minutes initially but +1 minute seemed to work) after the transaction that needed to S2S share the Account was completed

My other adventures with S2S are documented [here](http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen latency of up to a few hours occur at times before a record shared in one Org appears in another. This however does appear to be the exception rather than the rule. Generally updates appear almost instantly.

There is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XwxAAE) where updates to records can get lost and not make it to the org they are shared with if updates to a record happens more than once in a short period of time (less than a minute). This has been an issue for us with about 20 to 30 updates a month. Given that we are sharing a few thousand new records each month and each record receives 25-50 updates a month this is a small failure percentage.

Take a look at this [SE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64626/issues-with-salesforce-to-salesforce-sharing-intermittently-failing) if you are interested in more information.